# What exactly is an "issue" in Atomic Robo?

Tags: fate, atomic-robo

I have read the Atomic Robo RPG book, and it makes some mentions of "issues." What are these exactly a reference to, and why do they matter to the game? to be clear, I am not and would not complain about having more fate points, but I would like clarification as to why I, or any PC, would get them for this action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Issue" is exactly what it sounds like--the RPG equivalent of a single issue of a comic book. **It's a unit of story/plot** which usually lasts one or two sessions and runs from the resolution of one significant cliffhanger to the introduction of the next. **In ARRPG, issues replace the "session" unit of time for several mechanics.**

There's roughly a half-dozen issues in a typical story, and each issue has a particular problem —usually precipitated by the previous issue's cliffhanger, or the resolution of that cliffhanger— which is the focus of play. Also, every issue should contain a point where it's logical to have a minor milestone (instead of at the end of every session as in Fate Core, though functionally it may look similar at the table).

ARRPG 184 talks about issues --albeit more about *using* them than *defining* them-- and 185 provides a rough guideline for progression which breaks down a possible plot progression into four discrete units which map to one or two issues each. It should help give an idea of how the concept plays out in a game, especially if you haven’t read the *Atomic Robo* comics.